# What is cgroupfs and how is it used with Docker?

Tags: linux, docker

In the Docker documentation there is a discussion of options for the native execdriver (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/).  The documentation says

> The native.cgroupdriver option specifies the management of the
>   container’s cgroups. You can specify cgroupfs or systemd. If you
>   specify systemd and it is not available, the system uses cgroupfs. By
>   default, if no option is specified, the execdriver first tries systemd
>   and falls back to cgroupfs. This example sets the execdriver to
>   cgroupfs:

My question is what is `cgroupfs` and how does it compare to `systemd` in this case?  Googling for information about `cgroupfs` led to a [tweet](https://twitter.com/ibuildthecloud/status/638397128042135552):

> --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs FTW.  seriously @docker, drop support for cgroups managed by systemd, it's a disaster

But I'm hoping someone can provide more details about what this actually does rather than just saying use a setting that differs from the default.

Comment: You do realize this all has to do with allocating system (CPU) resources to a container, right? systemd has cgroup integration built in. Cgroupfs is a file-system view of the kernel's cgroup interface. If this is what you're looking for, I'll put it in an answer. But if you know this already, I'd have to dig through code.

Comment: @Otheus I didn't put the bounty on the question so I'm not sure what the person who did is interested in.  The main thing that motivated me to ask the question was a desire to understand why someone recommended using the option `--exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=cgroupfs`.  But I suspect if you wrote an answer explaining the setting that is easier for a beginner to understand than what is in the Docker documentation that you would get some upvotes and it would might be helpful to people finding the question from Google in the future too.

Answer (score 2):

As I can see from comment in sources in: `vendor/src/github.com/opencontainers/runc/libcontainer/factory_linux.go`

```
// Cgroupfs is an options func to configure a LinuxFactory to return
// containers that use the native cgroups filesystem implementation to
// create and manage cgroups.
```

`cgroupfs` seem to be own docker (`libcontainer`) implementation which configures containers `cgroups` writing directly to files on `cgroups-file-system` (e.g. mounted in `/sys/fs/cgroup/`).